# Multi-Line Brackets

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I can't seem to get the parenthesis to wrap around the RHS of the equality. I get the following error:
Errors:

```
./review.tex:239: Extra }, or forgotten \right. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing \right. inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing } inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing } inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Extra \right. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing { inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Extra }, or forgotten \right. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing \right. inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing } inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing } inserted. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Extra \right. [\end{split}]
./review.tex:239: Missing { inserted. [\end{split}]
```

From this code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(\hat{c}_{0}^{\dagger} + \hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger})\hat{t}_{0}^{\dagger} \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}= \\
(- c_{0}^{\dagger} c_{1}^{\dagger} + c_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} - c_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger 2}\\
+ c_{1}^{\dagger} t_{0}^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2} c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - \\
t_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} + t_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{1}^{\dagger 2} - \sqrt{2} t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger}\\
+ t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2} v_{c}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger}\right) \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

single line statements work--i've tested it.

Here's the working code, without the parenthesis I need.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\hat{c}_{0}^{\dagger} + \hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger})\hat{t}_{0}^{\dagger} \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}= \\
(- c_{0}^{\dagger} c_{1}^{\dagger} + c_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} - c_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger 2}\\
+ c_{1}^{\dagger} t_{0}^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2} c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - \\
t_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} + t_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{1}^{\dagger 2} - \sqrt{2} t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger}\\
+ t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2} v_{c}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger}\ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: I've updated the post.

Comment: @nick_name MWE is a (maybe badly) compilable example. In such a case one neednt't guess, e.g., used packages.

Comment: There is *no* need to prefix `(` and `)` by `\left` and `\right`. In this case they are useless. Don't use them unless really necessary for making the parentheses grow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unbalanced `\left` ... `\right` (they must be in the same logical line).  An exemplary, however ugly, solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,braket}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
%\left(
(\hat{c}_{0}^{\dagger} + \hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger})\hat{t}_{0}^{\dagger} \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}= \\
\Bigl(- c_{0}^{\dagger} c_{1}^{\dagger} + c_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} - c_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger 2}\\
+ c_{1}^{\dagger} t_{0}^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2} c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - \\
t_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} + t_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{1}^{\dagger 2} - \sqrt{2} t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger}\\
+ t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + \sqrt{2} v_{c}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger}
%\right)
\Bigr)
 \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Przemysław's answer, I made it a little bit more beautiful. You do not need that big parenthesis at all. If you want to use an automated bracket like `\left(`, you have to 'close' it with `\right.` on the same line.

Here is my MWE. You could even reduce one row. There is enough space in order to make the equation a bit wider:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\newcommand*{\myStrut}{\vphantom{1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        (\hat{c}_{0}^{\dagger} + \hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger})\hat{t}_{0}^{\dagger} \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00} &= (c_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} - c_{0}^{\dagger} c_{1}^{\dagger} - c_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger\,2} + c_{1}^{\dagger} t_{0}^{\dagger} \\
        &\qquad+ \sqrt{2} c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c\myStrut}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} + t_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{1}^{\dagger\,2} \\ 
        &\qquad- \sqrt{2} t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c\myStrut}^{\dagger} + t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} \\
        &\qquad+ \sqrt{2} v_{c\myStrut}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger}) \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiline brackets, following Sébastien Gouezel's example on po. 28-29 of the `mathtools` documentation. In addition, I propose another alignment based on the `alignedat` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} %
\usepackage{braket}

\newcommand\MTkillspecial[1]{% helper macro
\bgroup
\catcode`\&=9
\let\\\relax%
\scantokens{#1}%
\egroup
}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\mlparen\lparen\rparen
\reDeclarePairedDelimiterInnerWrapper\mlparen{star}{
\mathopen{#1\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\right.}
#2
\mathclose{\left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace\vphantom{\MTkillspecial{#2}}#3}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\bigr(\hat{c}_{0}^{\dagger} + \hat{c}_{1}^{\dagger}\bigr)\hat{t}_{0}^{\dagger} \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00} & =
{}&\mlparen[\big]{& {- c_{0}}^{\dagger} c_{1}^{\dagger} + c_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} - c_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger 2} + c_{1}^{\dagger} t_{0}^{\dagger} \\
& &&\! + √{2} c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger} + c_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{0}^{\dagger} t_{1}^{\dagger} + t_{0}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} - t_{1}^{\dagger 2} \\
& & &\! - √{2} t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{c}^{\dagger}+ t_{1}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger} + √{2} v_{c}^{\dagger} v_{t}^{\dagger}} \ket{0000}\otimes\ket{00}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]